# Android Export to aar - jar containing redundant package

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have library project in Android. When I build the project in order to produce the `aar` file, I get inside the `jar` file which is important to us.

The `jar` file structure is following:

```
com
  |
  package I need
               | BuildConfig.class
  redundant package
META-INF
```

The point is that my project doesn't contain the redundant package but from her name I suspect maybe somewhere someone defined it as "package name" or something like this for the whole project, and this is it's leftovers.

I tried from the `gradle.build` script to ignore it when creating the `jar` but it's not working:

```
...
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            exclude 'com/redundant_package_name/**'
        }
...
```

How can I get rid off this redundant package in the `jar`? Thanks,

Comment: if you have a redundant package name, how is gradle supposed to know which one you are trying to exclude? You can try to exclude the subclasses - and also remove dependencies until you identify the one with a problem, then look for alternatives. But we need more information to help.

Comment: @Jim In gradle script after exclude I give the name of the redundant package name, is this mistake? The point is that I don't see the package and ain't subclasses. Rather I do see this package name in the manifest as "package name" of the app (in this case Android library because its library project), so I suspect from there is the problem. Can I just rename it to the name of the package I really need? Because I know this is the things that should be not changed. Although in this case this is library that distributed outside play market so maybe no problem?